# Always show loading animation when navigating between pages?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm forcefully testing my app on a bad internet to see how user experiences navigation through my app, I'm having problems showing a loader on certain events.

The loaders work fine on events already inside a page, when I put them in ajax calls:

```
        beforeSend: function() {
            $.mobile.loading("show");
        },
        complete: function() {
            $.mobile.loading("hide");
        },
```

But they don't work too good on events like pagecreate or pagebeforeshow, example:

```
$("#points").on("pagecreate", function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: hb_base_url + "consumer/" + user_id + "/merchants/nature/" + business_point_search + "/offset/" + offset + "/" + limit,
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function() {
            $.mobile.loading("show");
        },
        complete: function() {
            $.mobile.loading("hide");
        },
        success: function(data) {
            //do stuff
        },
        error: function(x, t, m) {
            alert(connection_lost);
            $.mobile.back();
        }
    });
});
```

When I navigate to this page, and my connection hangs, I get no loading at all, it just hangs there and the user gets the feeling that the app has crashed.

Is there any setting to go around this? I would like to show a loader in all my page changes, waiting for all page events to complete before hiding it.

**Edit**
I have also tried:

```
$(document).on("pagebeforehide", function(){
    $.mobile.loading("show");
});


$(document).on("pageshow", function(){
    $.mobile.loading("hide");
});
```

But no success, even on pages that take ages to change.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the global call back functions such as [`ajaxStart`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart) and [`ajaxStop`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop) to predefine your `beforeSend` and `complete` options :

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    $.mobile.loading('show');
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    $.mobile.loading('hide');
});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    $.mobile.loading('hide');
});
```

Comment: There are many calls in my app that don't require the loading to trigger, and if these don't work on a specific AJAX call, why are you inclined to believe they would work on ajaxStart/Stop/etc.